# Alpine.js & jQuery DataTables, x-on:click disfunctional when trigger inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables, alpine.js

I have this table in my Laravel and Alpine.js blade page.

```
<table id="projects-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($projects as $project)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
            <td><button x-data="{}" x-on:click="$dispatch('open-modal', 'edit-project')">edit</button></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With it I have this JavaScript code to turn it into a jQuery DataTable

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    new DataTable('#projects-table');
});
```

Now what happens is, my modal doesn't trigger when I click the `button` inside the `td`

When the table is not a DataTable, everything works fine.

What is basically happening (probably) the @click event doesn't fire when the element is manipulated by jQuery. Is there any known fix for this? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution may be to wrap the table in a tag controlled by Alpine and initialize the table after Alpine starts:

```html
<div x-data>

   <table id="projects-table">
   
      <!-- ..... -->

   </table>

</div>

<script>
   document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
       new DataTable('#projects-table')
   });
</script>
```

In this way Alpine can detect when the DOM is changed by DataTables and then rebuild his references.

Otherwise in your specific case you can send the custom event using vanilla JS and leave the other things unchanged:

```
<!-- ..... -->

<td>
    <button onclick="window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('open-modal', { detail: 'edit-project' }))">
        Edit
    </button>
</td>

<!-- ..... -->

<!-- Simple example for the modal triggering -->
<div x-data="{isOpen: false}" x-show="isOpen" @open-modal.window="isOpen = true">
   I'm open!
<div>
```